# Water Heater Not Working After Replacing Both Thermostats and Testing Elements

Tags: water, water-heater

I replaced both the upper and lower thermostats with new ones. I tested the elements with a multi-meter and the top one was 15 ohms and the bottom one was about 12 ohms so they seem to be fine. I even tested the elements to see if there was any voltage and there was. I'm about to replace both elements to see if that does anything. Any ideas?

Also something to note when I put the test leads on both of the element terminal screws I don't get a reading. I'm not sure if that has any significance.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Update so I was going to replace the upper thermostat and I couldn't get it out. I looked inside and this is what I saw
[image]

I'm guessing that green thing is the dip tube and its melted on to the element. I don't see how this is causing the element to not heat up though.

Comment: What voltage is your water heater? What is the model number? You said you tested the elements  and they had power. Only one element should have power at a time. Which one had power?

Comment: You have a resistance on the elements that look good but no voltage ? It sounds like the thermostats or supply, since you just changed the thermostats I would be looking to check the supply for 240v leg to leg at the heater and 120v from each leg to ground this will give us a clue if you have an open leg or other possible problems as most water heaters no not require a neutral.

Comment: The water heater is 240V. The thermostats are wired for off peak http://waterheatertimer.org/How-to-wire-water-heater-thermostats.html (third one down) I just tested the supply at the top and I'm getting 240V. I have included an update in my original post. I don't know if this could be causing the problem?